# Problem with jenkins headless browser test

Tags: hudson, cucumber, watir, jenkins

We are testing some Watir tests and cucumber using Jenkins but we have run into a problem with inconsistent results. Our build failed because apparently the watir attach popup browser was failing(couldn't find the window with the title we produced).

We double checked this by going into the workspace folder and running cucumber manually inside it compared with running cucumber by starting a build with Jenkins.

The Jenkins build failed with the popups while running cucumber inside the workspace folder didn't fail anything. We are guessing that this is because the browser is headless and thus it has no address bar or title bar? Is this the reason?

If so, is there any way around this? How do we attach a popup from a headless browser?

I am using watir 1.8.1(the main one) and IE8 on windows.

Comment: I think providing watir gem name (there are a few of them) and version and browser (and version) could help.

Comment: @Zeljko updated the question with the proper gem version watir(1.8.1) and IE8 on windows

Comment: I remember seeing questions like this at [watir-general](http://groups.google.com/group/watir-general/) (do not have the time to find an example now).

Comment: yeah ive been trying to use the watir search and all the guidelines for asking questions in the wait/support site but im afraid im out of luck. will timebox for another hour or so then i guess i'll ask in the mailing list after

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have to be logged in for popup tests to work:

- http://groups.google.com/group/watir-general/browse_thread/thread/27561fa8429b36c/
- http://groups.google.com/group/watir-general/browse_thread/thread/c95462c2ecc93209/

(Tip: when searching watir-general, search for hudson, not jenkins.)

Comment: Is the logged in you're refering to the Windows user or the hudson user? We have set this up so that hudson/jenkins is run as a service by the Administrator(logged in). Is there another way to logging in for watir?

Comment: I think you have to be logged in as a user, meaning you can see the screen.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that Watir-Webdriver has better support for running headless than Watir does.  Watir itself is really designed to automate the actual IE browser, and potentially some things may not work right if IE is not actually rendering the UI to a screen.

Watir-Webdriver supports IE, FF, Chrome, and Headless.  See [this entry](http://watirmelon.com/2010/12/14/watir-webdriver-a-detailed-introduction/) from Alister Scott's [Watirmelon blog](http://watirmelon.com) where he gives an example of how to run it headless using htmlunit

Comment: i would like to use watir-webdriver also but in our project that's not the case. it's some sort of a legacy app so we have to stick with plain watir. is there a way to run it without the headless mode?

Comment: You could probably hack something up using autologin, and a script that is set to run at startup that looks for some kind of indicator (like a file written to a specific directory) that it's time to run the script (and the script itself clears that file, or renames it, when done). Not exactly elegant, but it can be made to work.  Frankly, given that the differences between watir and watir-webdriver are relatively minimal, it might be worth making the few small changes needed to use watir-webdriver and see if they run.. revert to original versions if nogo (source control is your friend)

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Start->run "services.msc", find the Jenkins service, rightclick -> properties, go to the Log On tab, click the checkbox "Allow service to interact with desktop"

Works fine for me on XP as long as I run them at night, otherwise it gets annoying.